# how to repaint an inner class java awt

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to update the color of a circle when the user move sliders using java awt standalone (homework).I have to use a Frame. I can see that my values update form the slider but I can get those values to the inner class circle in the paint method to be repainted and update the color of the circle(the objective)
thanks for any help!!
this is my code so far:

```
package cs111b;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class ColorFactory extends Frame implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Dimension t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Panel pS,cP,rB;
    Scrollbar rScroll, gScroll, bScroll;
    Checkbox hex, dec, oct,bin;
    int[] Red = new int[4];
    int[] Green = new int[4];
    int[] Blue = new int[4];
    int[] rgb = new int[3];
    Color cl = new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
    Dimension Cr = new Dimension((int)(t.width*.70),(int)(t.height*.60));
    int w = 300;
    int x = (Cr.width/2)-(w/2);
    int y = (Cr.height/2)-(w/2);

    class Circle extends Canvas
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Dimension Cr = new Dimension((int)(t.width*.70),(int)(t.height*.60));
        int w = 300;
        int x = (Cr.width/2)-(w/2);
        int y = (Cr.height/2)-(w/2);
        //Color c;// = new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
        public Circle(int[] c)
        {
            cl = new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
        setSize(Cr);

        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            //c = new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
            g.setColor(cl);
            g.fillOval(x, y, w, w);
        }
    }
    class Rect extends Canvas
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Rect()
        {

        }

        public Rect(int x,int y,int w, int h)
        {
            Red[0] = x;
            Red[1] = y;
            Red[2] = w;
            Red[3] = h;
        }
      @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(Red[0], Red[1], Red[2], Red[3]);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(Green[0], Green[1], Green[2], Green[3]);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(Blue[0], Blue[1], Blue[2], Blue[3]);
        }

    }

    public ColorFactory()
    {
        addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        );
        setSize(t);
        setTitle("Color Factory");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //*****************Creating Label
        Label l = new Label("Color Factory");
        l.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(t.width,(int)(t.height*.1)));
        l.setFont(new Font("Seriff",Font.BOLD,35));
        l.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        add(l);
        //******************Creating Scrolls
        rScroll = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL,0,1,0,255);
        gScroll = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL,0,1,0,255);
        bScroll = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL,0,1,0,255);
        rScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,20));
        gScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,20));
        bScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,20));
        //******************Creating Panel
        pS = new Panel();
        pS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(t.width, (int)(t.height*.10)));
        pS.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        //rScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(this.getWidth()*.2),(int)(this.getHeight()*.02)));
        rScroll.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        gScroll.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        bScroll.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        rgb[0]= rScroll.getValue();
        rgb[1]= gScroll.getValue();
        rgb[2]= bScroll.getValue();
        pS.add(rScroll);
        pS.add(gScroll);
        pS.add(bScroll);
        add(pS);
        //Creating Circle
        cP = new Panel();
        cP.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        cP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(t.width*.70), (int)(t.height*.60)));
        Circle C = new Circle(rgb);
        C.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        //C.setForeground(Color.cyan);
        C.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(t.width*.70), (int)(t.height*.60)));
        cP.add(C);
        add(cP);
        //creating radio buttons panel
        rB = new Panel();
        rB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(t.width*.27), (int)(t.height*.60)));
        rB.setBackground(Color.RED);
        //Creating CheckBoxes
        CheckboxGroup cg = new CheckboxGroup();
        hex = new Checkbox("Hex",cg,true);
        dec = new Checkbox("Dec",cg,true);
        oct = new Checkbox("Oct",cg,true);
        bin = new Checkbox("Bin",cg,true);
        rB.add(hex);
        rB.add(dec);
        rB.add(oct);
        rB.add(bin);
        //creating Rectangles
        Red[0] = (int)(rB.getWidth()*.20);Red[1]= (int)(rB.getHeight()*8);Red[2] = 20; Red[3]= rScroll.getValue();
        Green[0] = (int)(rB.getWidth()*.20)+40;Green[1]= (int)(rB.getHeight()*8);Green[2] = 20; Red[3]= rScroll.getValue();
        Blue[0] = (int)(rB.getWidth()*.20)+80;Blue[1]= (int)(rB.getHeight()*8);Blue[2] = 20; Blue[3]= rScroll.getValue();
        Rect r = new Rect();
        r.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());


        rB.add(r);
        add(rB);
        rScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        gScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        bScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    /*
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paint(g);
        //g.setXORMode(cl);
        g.setColor(cl);
        g.fillOval(x, y, w, w);

    }
    */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ColorFactory();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) 
    {
        if(rScroll.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            Red[3]= e.getValue();
            rgb[0]= e.getValue();
            cP.setForeground(new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]));
            cP.repaint();
        }
        if(gScroll.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            rgb[1] = e.getValue();
            cP.repaint();

        }
        if(bScroll.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            rgb[2] = e.getValue();
            cP.repaint();

        }

        rB.repaint();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would any teacher assign a homework assignment that requires the use of AWT? That's been obsolete for almost 20 years. At the very least it should be Swing.

Comment: I agree 100%!! this is the stuff from his age...

Comment: Mr Abbas its giving you something to think lol . look at your notes on your first week lectures , he talk about constructors , set and get methods .

Comment: its funny to read that awt is obsolete almost 20 years ago , because is hard to see a swing that does not have a import java.awt.*; and the only java that i know is not using awt is javafx (release in 2014) , so how come is obsolete for almost 20 years?  and this obsolete question is here for 4 days and no answer . ps: i agree that awt is old and swing is better but obsolete over 20 years i dont think so. if you look on your ow code in this link you used awt  on your firts 2 line of code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009631/jpanel-gets-paintcomponent-gets-called-when-child-is-entered